# Dual Boot On Galaxy Note 2 ? ( Android / Ubuntu )

Tags: dual-boot, ubuntu-touch, android, phone, tablet

I want to buy a Galaxy Note 2 tablet/phone and I just wanted to know: how can I have both of these OS's on it at the same time?

If there is a way, how can I do it?

Is there anyone who can help me?

(I'm not a Linux programmer so the method would have to be for an Ubuntu beginner.)

I'm not talking about "Ubuntu for android"! I'm thinking something like having Meego and Android on a NOKIA N9, choosing the OS while starting up (dual boot). I want to run the *full* version Of Ubuntu along side the *full* version of Android.

Comment: Please clarify: You are asking for instructions on how to install the desktop version of Ubuntu, not Ubuntu Touch as for example described in this tutorial: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. Check out [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1872752) post on xdadevelopers.Hope it helps!! :)

Comment: That's not really dual booting...  Really dual booting is using something like multirom, which I'm not sure works for the Galaxy Note 2.